# How to find stable and unstable manifolds for nonlinear ode?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am working through Teschl's book on Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems and am in particular stuck on the last part of question 9.5 which asks to find the stable and unstable manifolds of the origin for the equation

$$
\ddot{x} = x - x^3
$$

After rephrasing the equation as a system of equations by setting $x_1 = x$, $x_2 = \dot{x}$, I found the Jacobian at the origin to be

$$
A = Df_{(0,0)} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

From which I get eigenvalues $\lambda = -1, 1$ corresponding to eigenvectors $v_1 = (-1,1)$, $v_2 = (1,1)$, respectively.  I can then find the linear stable and unstable sets (for the origin) to be

$$
E^{+} = \{ (x,y) | y = -x \}
$$
$$
E^{-} = \{ (x,y) | y = x \}
$$

However, I am now at a loss for how to finish the problem.  The preceding section of the book proved the existence of the stable and unstable manifolds but in an indirect way which used a "projection like operator" to project onto the manifolds without ever constructively defining how to find such a thing.  I therefore have no clue how to actually go about finding the (nonlinear) stable and unstable manifolds.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a conservative system because it is of special form $\ddot{x} = -\nabla F$ and if you mulitpy this by $\dot{x}$ and integrate you will get that $\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2} + F(x) = {\rm const}$ along a trajectory and this is a first integral of the system. For conservative system it is easy to show that unstable and stable manifold of equilibrium point lie in the same level set of first integral as an equilibrium itself. So just check how the level set that contains your equilibrium looks like.

Comment: @Evgeny That is very helpful!  If you write that as an answer, I will accept it.  As a further question--this equation is a special form of duffing's equation.  If we had retained the $- \delta \dot{x}$ term on the right side of the original equation, is there a general strategy for how the problem could still be attacked?

Comment: In case of Duffing equation with friction the best you can hope for is to describe these manifolds locally. You can represent (un)stable manifold as a graph $y = h(x)$. If you have a system $\dot{x} = P(x, y), \; \dot{y} = Q(x, y)$ then you can find derivatives of $h(x)$ by differentiating $y = h(x)$ w.r.t. to time. You will get $\dot{y} = h'(x) \cdot \dot{x}$ or $Q(x, h(x)) = h'(x) \cdot P(x, h(x))$. This is described in many books: Shilnikov-Shilnikov-Turaev-Chua, for example, Wiggins, Meiss.